# append data to column already has data

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to build a statics system

i want list all pages in one column, with `,` as a seprator between pages

for example

```
visitor_ip | pages_visited
122.32.223.2 | /,/post/20/,category/php,post/12,tag/hi
23.32.55.22 | /post/20,post/12
23.39.34.1 | /category/start
```

i am using `,` as a seprator

Now i want know how to append something to the column already have data?

How to update this

```
23.39.34.1 | /category/start
```

To

```
23.39.34.1 | /category/start,post/12
```

i want something like this

```
mysql_query("update statics SET pages_visited = pages_visited.','.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] WHERE visitor_ip = '$ip'");
```

I DID NOT TRY THIS QUERY, BUT I THINK .. IT WILL NEVER WORKS!

So, what is the correct query for this job?

Comment: "i want list all pages in one column, with , as a seprator between pages" --- it is a terrible solution. Create another table with columns `visitor | page` and fill it by rows as 1 row - 1 page per visitor (it is called one-to-many)

Comment: i have a reasons to use this solution..

Comment: there is no reason ever to prefer comma separated list over normalized schema

Comment: @zerkms you are right.. i've changed my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better method would be:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE statics 
             SET pages_visited = CONCAT(pages_visited,',',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) 
             WHERE visitor_ip = '$ip'");
```